# como puedo agregar mayor texto en el TexView

Tags: java, android, activity

estoy haciendo una aplicación en android studio para el curso de biología y deseo colocar:descripción, definiciones, imágenes, etc. Dejo unas imágenes de referencia. Gracias

Al colocar el siguiente código

```
 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/text_id"
  android:layout_width="300dp"
  android:layout_height="200dp"
  android:capitalize="characters"
  **android:text="hello_world"**
  android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
  android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
  android:textSize="50dp"/>
```

android text: "Hello_word" al colocar más texto en esta parte me sale error, que puedo hacer para poder aumentar mas las lineas de texto y tenga un formato organizado. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué tal amigo @JoseRomani, no entendí bien tu pregunta, de por si ¿cuál es el problema?, se me viene a la mente que quieres agregar tu descripcion, imagenes,etc pero no te alcanza espacio.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo: 1. si deseo colocar imágenes y descripciones como un libro. y el 2. es una apk móvil. gracias

Comment: De acuerdo a la primera imagen puedes colocar un ImageView para la imagen y abajo un TextView. Si deseas lo que se muestra en la segunda imagen puedes cargar directamente la página en un WebView

Comment: si son muchas imágenes con descripciones usa recyclerview, para la segunda imágen usa master-detail

Comment: ¿Estas realizando el programa con Java? Por lo que veo imagino que el diseño lo realizas en xml deberías mirar un poco la documentación del elemento [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) para poder resolver tus dudas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deseas es que al agregar más texto este pueda ser visible, en este caso necesita que se pueda desplazar.

---

#### Texto desplazable en TextView.

Para esto puedes establecer a tu `TextView` un método de movimiento de desplazamiento, lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Puedes definir si lo necesitas que tu `TextView` muestre la barra de desplazamiento vertical, agregando la propiedad :

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

De esta forma podrías realizar lo siguiente:

[image: elenasys jorgesys nunta]

Agrego también un ejemplo del layout que usarías:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="271dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="Scroll my text!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myImageView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: buenas tardes, realice los pasos que mencionas, mi duda seria donde colocas todo ese texto ... android:text = "Scrooll my text!" . gracias . saludos